# What's the purpose of -Wbad-function-cast, why does it only apply to the direct return value?

Tags: c, gcc-warning

There's a rationale for the warning [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306784/what-is-the-purpose-of-gccs-wbad-function-cast), but that fails to answer the whole picture. For example the following code triggers the warning:

```
(int)round(M_PI);
```

but on the other hand the following code doesn't:

```
double d;
(int)(d = round(M_PI));
```

this doesn't either:

```
(int)M_PI;
```

the rationale was that you shouldn't convert to int by simply casting, but you should use `round`, `floor` or similar function. However using `round` will still trigger the warning, but as seen above typecasting a constant or assigned variable doesn't.

So if it's that bad to cast from `double` to `int`, then why doesn't the warning trigger when you write `(int)d` or `(int)M_PI`? In what way is one supposed to circumvent the warning in case you want to convert the return value? Is there a warning that would handle these perilous conversions in a more correct/reasonable way?

Answer (score 9):

> `-Wbad-function-cast` (C and Objective-C only)
>
> Warn when a function call is cast to a non-matching type. For example, warn if a call to a function returning an integer type is cast to a pointer type.

As its name suggests, `-Wbad-function-cast` only warns when you are casting **function calls** to a non-matching type. It doesn't warn on all casts. This explains why you are not getting that warning for your last two examples:

- `(int)(d = round(M_PI));` doesn't trigger a warning because it is casting `double d` to `int` [after it has been assigned a value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9514569/2038264).
- `(int)M_PI;` doesn't trigger a warning because [`M_PI` is usually implemented as `#define M_PI 3.14159...`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15231836/2038264); it is simply a numeric token and not a function call.

You are right that it could be bad to cast from `double` to `int` as you are potentially losing information. You could avoid the GCC warning by simply assigning the function return value to a matching type, then casting later, as in your two examples that don't trigger the warning.

Of course, the point of the warning is not to force you to write extra code to do the same thing. Even for functions that "return an integral value" like `round()`, [the return value may be too big to fit in an `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1253670/2038264). What you should be doing is **checking to see if the value is safe to cast first**.

Comment: So, what do you do when the value is manifestly safe to cast to an int, so a test is unnecessary? I'm getting the error for something like: int x = ceil((int)y * sine(r)); This is an integer multiplied by a value less than or equal to 1. I shouldn't have to prove to the compiler that this is valid.

Comment: @swestrup The C language isn't sophisticated enough to recognise that functions return values within a fixed range, so it would be impossible for a standards-compliant compiler to know this too.

Comment: Yes, so the diagnostic then MUST produce false positives. Since that is so, why have it?

Answer (score 0):

If you like the warning generally but are annoyed that there's no way to write an explicit cast that suppresses it, on GCC you can do this:

```
_Pragma ("GCC diagnostic push");                            
_Pragma ("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wbad-function-cast\"");
OCR1A = ((uint16_t) (function_returning_double));          
_Pragma ("GCC diagnostic pop");
```

I would only resort to this in contexts where you don't want to introduce an intermediate value (i.e. in a macro).  As others have noted (in here: [What is the purpose of gcc's -Wbad-function-cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306784/what-is-the-purpose-of-gccs-wbad-function-cast)), a gratuitous lrint()/lround() might not get optimized away.  And inserting an intermediate value in a macro is unhygienic.